# deleting columns from a text file in java

Tags: java, text

i have a text file containing binary numbers how do i delete a column from the text file

1 0 1 1 0

0 1 1 0 1

1 1 1 0 1

0 1 0 0 1

for e.g. i want to delete the second column(0 1 1 1).Is there any way it can be done?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: "Is there any way it can be done?" Yes.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174201/deleting-parts-of-a-data-file-in-java)

Comment: Just loop through the file, searching for  \n's or \r's and then from there it is easy to remove it and reassemble it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("input.txt")));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));

    int skipIndex = 2; //we want to delete a 2nd column

    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        StringBuilder outLine = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            if (i + 1 != skipIndex) {
                outLine.append(" " + parts[i]);
            }
        }
        out.println(outLine.toString().trim());
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```